# How can I convey to a player that they need to hold the screen?

Tags: screen, tutorials

My game has similar mechanics as Flappy Bird game. When you tap or hold the screen with your finger, character goes up. Everybody who tested the game forgot to hold touching the screen, instead they played it only tapping the screen which made some parts of the game difficult to pass.

I want to display a tutorial at the beginning of the game. English is not my native language so I am a little bit confused. Which message is grammatically correct?

```
Hold the screen to fly
```

or

```
Hold on to the screen to fly
```

or

```
Hold your finger on the screen to fly
```

If anybody displayed a similar message in their game, can you share it with me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [ell.se] instead.

Comment: In fact, I'm not even sure it would fit their rules. But you certainly have enough rep to ask your question in their [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) :)

Comment: I suggest you display an animation that _shows_ how to make the character go up, like a thumb pressing the screen while the character goes up, instead of writing it. "Show, don't tell!" By doing this, you have your game in multiple languages at no cost (no need for translations)!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I was hoping to find a developer who used a similiar sentence like that. I will try my chance on English Learners Exchange. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Good luck :)